# Get ArchiveEntry fields through the Item API

Tags: sitecore-api

Is it possible to retrieve the fields of an `ArchiveEntry` type using Sitecore Item API? e.g. `archiveEntry.Fields["FieldName"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of get fields of archive entry with Sitecore API.

`ArchiveEntry` class contains only

- information about archiving process (date, origin database, who archived the item)
- original item ID
- original item name
- original item location

Archived fields are stored in SQL databases (core, master and web) in `ArchivedFields` table

When item is archived, all the shared fields, versioned fields and unversioned fields are added to `ArchivedFields` table, item data is added to `ArchivedItems` table and after it's done, item itself is removed from the original database.

---

**EDIT** to answer question from the comment

Yes, it's possible to get values of archived fields if you query database directly if you know id of the item which is archived. Query like that should do the trick:

```
SELECT af.[VersionId]
      ,af.[FieldId]
      ,af.[Value]
      ,ai.ItemId
FROM 
  [ArchivedFields] af JOIN [ArchivedItems] ai ON af.ArchivalId = ai.ArchivalId
WHERE
  ItemId = 'B09F6C56-E59B-420F-A669-130ED3A46C3F'
```

Comment: so it's possible to get the fields if i query directly to `ArchivedFields` table?

Comment: yes, answer updated

Comment: thanks. marked answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to provide a more detailed report with SPE.

```
Import-Function -Name Invoke-SqlCommand

$connection = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings]::GetConnectionString("master")

$query = @"
SELECT 
    ai.[ItemId]
    ,ai.[Name]
    ,ai.[TemplateId]
    ,ai.[ParentId]
    ,af.[VersionId]
    ,af.[FieldId]
    ,af.[Value]
      
FROM [ArchivedFields] af JOIN [ArchivedItems] ai ON af.ArchivalId = ai.ArchivalId
"@
Invoke-SqlCommand -Connection $connection -Query $query | Show-ListView
```

[image: Example]